# Simple Kafka Consumer Example not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple class to consume messages from a kafka server. The majority of codes are copied from the comments of org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.java.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.144.10:29092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "1000");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "10000");
        KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]>(props);
        consumer.subscribe("voltdbexportAUDIT", "voltdbexportTEST");
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            Map<String, ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]>> records = consumer.poll(100);
            process(records);
        }
        consumer.close();
    }

    private static Map<TopicPartition, Long> process(Map<String, ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]>> records) {
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> processedOffsets = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]>> recordMetadata : records.entrySet()) {
            List<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> recordsPerTopic = recordMetadata.getValue().records();
            for (int i = 0; i < recordsPerTopic.size(); i++) {
                ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = recordsPerTopic.get(i);
                // process record
                try {
                    processedOffsets.put(record.topicAndPartition(), record.offset());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return processedOffsets;
    }
}
```

I am using 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.0'. it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "key.deserializer" which has no default value.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:430)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:400)
    at kafka.integration.Demo.main(Demo.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

How should I config the key.deserializer?

Comment: Look more carefully at the example that you copied from. It's in there.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you can point out the place.

Answer (score 21):

This works out of the box without implementing your own serializers

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("group.id", "test");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  
props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "range");
```

Answer (score 4):

For keys use one of the following

**String Key**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
```

**JSON Key**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

**Avro Key**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
```

**ByteArray Key**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
```

---

Likewise, use one of the following for your value deserializer:

**String Value**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
```

**JSON Value**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

**Avro Value**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
```

**ByteArray Value**

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
```

---

Note that for Avro deserialisers, you will need the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId> 
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId> 
    <version>${confluent.version}</version> 
</dependency> 

<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId> 
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId> 
    <version>${avro.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the properties:

```
props.put("serializer.class","my.own.serializer.StringSupport");
props.put("key.serializer.class","my.own.serializer.LongSupport");
```

in your main method so that you pass them to the producer's constructor.  Of course, you'd have to specify the right encoders.  The serializer class converts the message into a byte array and the key.serializer class turn the key object into a byte array.  Generally you'd also have them be able to reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with byte array for key and value parameter.
So Byte serializer and deserializer required.

you can add in properties,

For Deserialize

```
props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
```

For Serialize

```
props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the string value of the deserialization class, rather than the class object (which was my mistake).

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
          Serdes.String().deserializer().getClass().getName());
```

When you forget the `.getName()`, you will get the same exception which in that case is misleading.